# Magento 2 : shipment email

Tags: magento2, shipment, shipment-tracking, shipment-email

I've created partially shipment functionality in magento2 now the problem is when i send the shipment email i got the every shipment traking id for that particular order but i want that particular shipment tracking id. but i dont know how can i do that. any help would be appreciate here i attach the code for the shipment email.

[image]

and here i attach the shipment email image

https://prnt.sc/15gm2fx

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you try

```
$shipment = $objectManager->create('Magento\Sale\Mode\Order\Shipment')->load($shipmentId);
$tracksCollection = $shipment->getTracksCollection();
            foreach ($tracksCollection->getItems() as $track) {
                $trackNumber = $track->getTrackNumber();
                $carrierName = $track->getTitle();
            }
```

Comment: and how do i send it to the mail?

Comment: To send an email you need to take more steps. You can check out the instructions here: https://bsscommerce.com/confluence/how-to-send-email-in-magento2/